# Error in feed dict TensorFlow with float input

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

Here is the piece of code

```
def train(x):
    prediction = cnn(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in xrange(num_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in xrange(int(1020/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = train_iterator.get_next()
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch {} completed out of {} - loss {}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, epoch_loss))
```

the line of the error is this

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
```

I read the data from a tfrecord file using this code

```
def read_image_dataset_tfrecordfile(filenames, color=False, resize=False, width=100, height=100):

    def parser(record):
        keys_to_features = {
            "image": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)
        image = tf.decode_raw(parsed["image"], tf.uint8)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        if resize:
            if color:
                image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[width, height, 3])
            else:
                image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[width, height, 1])
        label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.int32)
        label = tf.one_hot(label, 17)

        return {'image': image}, label

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(parser)

    return dataset
```

I printed for example one image and its label here

```
[[59.],
        [94.],
        [79.],
        ...,
        [41.],
        [42.],
        [43.]],

       [[56.],
        [86.],
        [91.],
        ...,
        [43.],
        [41.],
        [33.]],

       [[53.],
        [69.],
        [63.],
        ...,
        [56.],
        [59.],
        [51.]]], dtype=float32)}, array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      dtype=float32))
```

The image is float32 as the input of my network. You can see

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10000])
def cnn(x):
    weights = {
        'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 16])),
        'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 16])),
        'W_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 32])),
        'W_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 32])),
        'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([24 * 24 * 32, 1024])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
    }

    biases = {
        'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
        'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
        'b_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
        'b_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
        'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
        'b_out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }

    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 100, 100, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') +
                       biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv2, weights['W_conv3'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') +
                       biases['b_conv3'])
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv3, weights['W_conv4'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') +
                       biases['b_conv4'])
    conv4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    fc = tf.reshape(conv4, [-1, 24 * 24 * 32])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, dropout_rate)

    out = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['b_out']

    return out
```

I'm using the same network that I used with MNIST dataset from TensorFlow examples. The weights and biases are float so my input must be float right? With the MNIST dataset worked all like a charm but now it gives me this error and I can't figure out why.

**edit 1**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProveTF/main.py", line 109, in <module>
    train(x)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProveTF/main.py", line 84, in train
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1106, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

**edit 2**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProveTF/main.py", line 111, in <module>
    train(x)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProveTF/main.py", line 84, in train
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost])
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,100,100,1], [?,17]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]

Caused by op u'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProveTF/main.py", line 109, in <module>
    x, y = train_iterator.get_next()
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 330, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 866, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,100,100,1], [?,17]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

**edit 3**

```
def train(input):
    prediction = cnn(input)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in xrange(num_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in xrange(int(1020/batch_size)):
                try:
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost])
                    epoch_loss += c
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    train_set.repeat()

            print('Epoch {} completed out of {} - loss {}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, epoch_loss))
```

Comment: And what is the error exactly? Can you also paste a stacktrace?

Comment: Is too long, I edited the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `dict` / `array` cast error

There's too much code and dependencies to reproduce your problem.
It seems however to me that your error may come from your `parser(record)` function, which returns your images wrapped in a `dict` (c.f. `{'image': image}`, while it is not the case for your `label`). As `epoch_x` would then contain `dict` elements, Tensorflow (and numpy) would fail trying to convert them into the expected data type (a `tf.float32` tensor, c.f. definition of placeholder `x`), which may explain your cast-related error.

Long story short, try replacing `return {'image': image}, label` by `return image, label` in your parser.

---

#### Tensorflow Dataset API vs `feed_dict`

Somehow this problem escaped me at first. Given your Tensorflow-Dataset-based input pipeline, you are not supposed to use `placeholder` / `feed_dict`. The latter are meant to pass your data on the CPU to Tensorflow (supposedly running on GPUs). This duplication/conversion of the inputs done through `feed_dict` is much overhead, hence the development of the Tensorflow Dataset API, which short-circuits all this by reading and converting your data in parallel of the actual graph runs. In other words, your `epoch_x, epoch_y` don't need to be *fed* to Tensorflow ; they are already part of its graph.

Basically, your pipeline should look like something similar to the following:

```
train_dataset = read_image_dataset_tfrecordfile(my_filenames)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat() # if you want to loop indefinitely
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

x, y = train_iterator.get_next()
# x, y will represent your data batches, fed with the next ones every time 
# they are called.
# So you just use them directly instead of placeholders:
prediction = cnn(x) 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
    logits=prediction, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer().minimize(cost)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in xrange(num_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in xrange(int(1020/batch_size)):
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost])
            # ...
```

Comment: Nice shot! That was the problem. Now I have to find a way to transform this tensor in other stuff because it raises this error now: TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. Do you know a way to feed a Tensor without using feed dict?

Comment: I wrote:
epoch_x, epoch_y = sess.run(train_iterator.get_next())
and it seems to work except for an OutOfRange error which always gives me when I try to batch the dataset.

Comment: Right, I did miss the main error. Please check my updated answer. :)

Comment: Thank you. When I started following tutorials about tf.data.Dataset they always said that I hadn't to use feed dict anymore but they didn't show how. But the problem now is the same (you can see in the edit 2 in the main post). Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: It's a normal behavior. You just iterated over all your input data, reaching beyond the last batch (c.f. `OutOfRangeError`). See this [section](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_values_from_an_iterator) of the documentation for how to deal with it. If you want to loop several times over your dataset, you can also use [`dataset.repeat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat).

Comment: Solved thank you! I changed my code in this way (see edit 3). Now it works thank you

Comment: No sorry. The run was too fast to be executed in CPU so I debugged the code. The except catch the error but the dataset.repeat() doesn't do anything and basically, it doesn't work...

Comment: `dataset.repeat()` has to be done before you create the iterator from `dataset`. See my updated exemplary code.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before doing the try/catch but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Ok, found the error. Was in my images, the path was wrong.
Now I just have problems with the dimension of the Tensors in the net. Probably I did bad things, I'll figure out.

Comment: Problem found and solved but after one iteration through the dataset, it gives OutOfRangeError even if I wrote dataset.repeat(). The first epoch displays the total error and then (the dataset is finished) it throws the OutOfRange.